# can we create a index with unique values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df. Thise dataframe gets appended in every 5 mins. So I need to have unique values liek below

original df

```
df
ColA  ColB
A      56
B      40
C      20
```

1st time the df is loaded

```
df
ColA  ColB   ColC
A      56     1
B      40     2
C      20     3
```

2nd time the df is loaded

```
df
ColA  ColB   ColC
A      56     1
B      40     2
C      20     3
D      40     4
E      59     5
```

is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an index column like this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(colC = 1:n())

 #   ColA ColB colC
 #1    A   56    1
 #2    B   40    2
 #3    C   20    3
```

Or using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, colC := .I]
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), ColB = c(56L, 40L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks............

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it worked for you..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
df$colC <- seq(nrow(df))
```